# Equivalence of two optimization problem

Tags: calculus, optimization

Suppose I have a set of angles $\theta_k, 1 \leq k \leq n$, all between $[-\pi,\pi]$. Would the two minimization problems

$$
f_1(\theta) = \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{j}(\theta-\theta_j)^2
$$

and

$$
f_2(\theta) = \frac{1}{2n} \sum_j (1 - \cos(\theta-\theta_j))^2
$$

Lead to the same solution?

The closed form of the first one is the mean of all $\theta_j$'s, the second one I think it can only be solved with gradient descent or similar.

I don't think they're the same problem, since the second one can be transformed into the first one if all theta's are close to each other.

Is there formal way to prove/disprove they're the same problem?

Thank you

Comment: The results will be closed, but are likely to be different in the general case. The simplest way should be to show a counter example. At least $n=3$ seems necessary, with a non uniform distribution ...

Comment: What seems necessary?

Comment: With $n=2$, the mid angle will be optimal in both cases. Same with 3 angles, one of them being the average of the two others

Comment: It is a condition to find a counter example. Sorry if it is not clear

Comment: Could you please give these counter examples in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n=2$ they are equal. For $n=3$ they are not, since $\theta_1=\theta_2=0$, $\theta_3=\pi$ is a counterexample. We have $$f_2(\theta) = \frac{1}{6} \left(2\left(1-\cos(\theta)\right)^2 + \left(1-\cos(\theta-\pi)\right)^2\right),$$ whose minimum does *not* occur at $\pi/3 \approx 1.05$ as can be seen in [this graph](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiIyKigxLWNvcyh4KSleMisoMS1jb3MoeC1waSkpXjIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyIwLjczMTUzNDIxNjU2MDY0MDMiLCIxLjQ0NjIxNjc3NDYxNTA0MDMiLCIyLjM4OTcxMzU2OTc5MiIsIjIuODI5NTE4MjIwOTAyMzk5NyJdfV0-).